# C++ equals sign in function call?

Tags: c++

Reviewing some of the JUCE sample code, I ran across this function call:

```
Arpeggiator()
{
    addParameter (speed = new AudioParameterFloat ("speed", "Arpeggiator Speed", 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
}
```

Is this just an assignment within a function call? Or is there some other kind of c++ magic going on here?

Comment: I cannot tell because `=` operator may be overloaded and there are no declaration/definition of `speed` and its type.

Comment: Typically this is used to both assign the value of `speed` and pass this value on to `addParameter()` on the same line.

Comment: also addParameter might be a macro, not a function, maybe

Comment: @MikeCAT The `operator=()` can't be overloaded for  a `AudioParameterFloat *`. Well, `speed` could be something else, but according conventions the overloaded `operator=()` should return a reference to that instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this just an assignment within a function call?

Yes.

> Or is there some other kind of c++ magic going on here?

Not much *magic* there, the return value of an assignment operation usually is a reference to the instance assigned.

So it's equivalent to (I suspect that is constructor code):

```
class Arpeggiator : public Decorator {
public:
     Arpeggiator() {
         speed = new AudioParameterFloat ("speed", "Arpeggiator Speed", 0.0, 1.0, 0.5);
         addParameter (speed); // Probably inherited from Decorator 
     }
private: 
    AudioParameterFloat* speed;
};
```

---

As the [question came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597761/c-equals-sign-in-function-call/37597831?noredirect=1#comment62680767_37597831), what happens if there's an overloaded assignment operator.

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) in the canonical [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading):

> #### Assignment Operator
>
> There's a lot to be said about assignment. However, most of it has already been said in [GMan's famous Copy-And-Swap FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), so I'll skip most of it here, only listing the perfect assignment operator for reference:
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(X rhs)
> {
>    swap(rhs);
>    return *this;
> }
> ```

Comment: What if the `operator=` is overloaded and it does not return the same thing?

Comment: @NathanOliver The code will fail then, was that in question at any time?

Comment: @NathanOliver then the library's quite badly designed

Comment: On the other hand, it looks like the library's version of a named argument. One could argue that named arguments do not make sense outside of a function call, in which case an error for the extracted assignment would be expected.